# Guard create session async

Tags: symfony

I am using guard for user authentication, login is handled by html fetch api.

If login is successfull I get token for js auth to api, but I want after page update user to be logged in, but it's not.

In response I see set cookie for PHPSESSID and REMEMBERME but it's look like this cookie is not persisted.

I'm not sure, where can be problem, it looks like guard make his work just fine.

request is not cross-domain.

request headers:

```
GET /login/check-facebook?code=xxx HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
accept: application/json
content-type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
x-api-token: anon.
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en,cs;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
DNT: 1
```

response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxx; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Debug-Token: edb1db
X-Debug-Token-Link: /_profiler/edb1db
Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2016 15:12:32 GMT
Set-Cookie: REMEMBERME=xxx; expires=Tue, 19-Jan-2016 15:12:32 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; httponly
```

Firewall:

```
      main:
        provider: db_provider
        stateless:  false
        remember_me:
          secret: "%secret%"
          lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
          path:     /
          always_remember_me: true
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        logout: ~
        guard:
          authenticators:
              - authenticator.facebook
              - authenticator.email
          entry_point: authenticator.facebook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fount it.

In fetch api option `credentials: 'same-origin'` must be set.

Similar thing must be send with jquery or xhr. `withCredentials: true`

Comment: It's not to "persist cookie" but to send it back.